# Kesi Sutta, what is an untamable person?

Tags: theravada

> "It is true, Kesi, that it's not proper for a Tathagata to take life.
>   But if **a tamable person** doesn't submit either to a mild training or to
>   a harsh training or to a mild & harsh training, then the Tathagata
>   doesn't regard him as being worth speaking to or admonishing. His
>   knowledgeable fellows in the holy life don't regard him as being worth
>   speaking to or admonishing. This is what it means to be totally
>   destroyed in the Doctrine & Discipline, when the Tathagata doesn't
>   regard one as being worth speaking to or admonishing, and one's
>   knowledgeable fellows in the holy life don't regard one as being worth
>   speaking to or admonishing."

[AN 4.111](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.111.than.html)

Just so, is this subtle language? What then is an untamable person? Is it a being like an animal, who does not have access to Dhamma, or is it a being who has access to it, but disregards it out of hand, or something in between!?

Comment: Is like Devadatta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ven. Sujato translates it, "a person in training" (which makes sense in the context).

The word in question is [purisadamma](https://suttacentral.net/define/purisadamma).

Piya Tan [explains it here](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/52.3-Kesi-S-a4.111-piya.pdf) as follows:

> **1.3.3.2 What is *purisa*?** The usual translation for ***purisa*** is “person,” usually a “man.” And the usual
>   word for “individual” is *purisa*,*puggala* or simply *puggala*, as if famously used in reference to “the pairs of
>   persons, the 8 individuals” (*purisa,yugāni aṭṭha,purisa.puggalā*) in the recollection of the noble community (*saṅghânussati*).
>
> Here, *purisa* refers to a “person,” which loosely refers to a being with some capacity for thought and
>   will (in the sense of personal action).
>
> The Buddha has tamed animal persons (*tiracchāna,purisa*), such as the *naga-rajah Apalāla, Cūḷodara, Mahodara, Aggi,sikha, Dhūma,sikha*, the *naga-rajah Āravāla*, and the elephant *Dhana,pālaka*.
>
> He has tamed human persons (*manussa,purisa*), such as the young *nirgrantha Saccaka*, the brahmin
>   youth *Ambaṭṭha, Pokkhara,sāti, Soṇa,daṇa*, and *Kūṭa,danta*.
>
> He has tamed non-human persons (*amanussa,purisa*), such as the *yakshas Āḷavaka, Sūci,loma* and
>   *Khara,loma*, and *Sakra*, the lord of the devas.
>
> **1.3.3.3 What is *damma*?** The word ***damma*** (Skt *damya*)
>   is an adjective, the gerundive of *dameti*
>   (causative: Skt *dāmyati*), “to bring into the house, to domesticate; to tame, convert; to be restrained;
>   especially with reference to tamable animals; figuratively, to humans to be tamed or converted.” Technically, *damma* means “to be tamed, or should be tamed,” but the context here clearly refers to the
>   capacity or readiness of a being or person for taming—hence, “tamable.”
>
> **“Tamable persons”** (*purisa,damma*), that is, those to be trained, according to the Sutta are of 4 kinds:
>   (1) those who are trained with gentleness; [1.3.4.1]
>   (2) those who are trained with harshness; [1.3.4.2]
>   (3) those who are trained both ways (with gentleness and with harshness); [1.3.4.3] and
>   (4) those who cannot be trained at all: the untamable. [1.3.5]

Comment: Thanks, that was quick :) just as an afterthought, that Piya Tan format of suttas, is there a suttacentral style repository for the lot of them one can hit up?

Comment: Yes look at the bottom of the right-hand column of http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/ -- for example the link to AN 4.111 is on http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/sutta-titles-2/anguttara-nikaya -- unfortunately the link there i.e. http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/15.7-Buddhanussati-piya.pdf is often out of date ("Page not found") -- so to find it then I use a Google search of the site, like https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awww.themindingcentre.org+kesi+sutta